# Force child classes to override method

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, overriding, oop

How can I make it so that any class that inherits from my base class is forced to override a specific method? I don't want to use a protocol, because that wouldn't make this behavior automated.

```
@interface MyBaseClass : NSObject 
{
}

- (void)performAnAction;

@end

@implementation MyBaseClass

- (void)performAnAction
{
    @throw([NSException exceptionWith...]);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

How exactly do you mean, force them to override it? If you simply implement the parent method like so:

```
- (void)performAction {
    NSAssert(NO, @"The method %@ in %@ must be overridden.",
         NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), NSStringFromClass([self class]));
}
```

then it'll throw an exception at runtime if the child class fails to override it. Unfortunately there is no way to enforce this at compile-time.

Comment: So it's not possible to display a warning either?

Comment: Nope. Just document the class appropriately so that it's obvious that this method needs to be overridden.

Comment: @JamesBillingham: Anyone who writes a subclass that calls `[super performAction]` will learn really quickly that it's not appropriate in this case. Ideally the class header would document that any implementors should not call `super`.

Comment: I implemented a #if defined DEBUG NSLOg & NSAssert so that it at least doesn't crash on release. FWIW

Answer (score 1):

You could just throw an exception. As long as this is well documented, then IMO this is a reasonable use of exceptions since it truly is a programming error.